# How to dynamically create multiple columns for a long list using cocoon gem and nested fields in a rails 5 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

I presently have cocoon gem working for a single column. User adds questions to quiz.  When User gets to 10 questions, I want a new column to start.  When user deletes a question or many questions the appropriate divs or nodes should be removed. There will be a maximum of 30 questions so potentially 3 columns. I do not know to do this within the cocoon gem way.  I can't quite figure out the documentation offered on their ReadME at GITHUB where they discuss node insertion methods. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way, I would suggest, is doing some javascript when you add a node...

```
        $(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, question) {
          // count the number of questions 
          var count = $('.nested-fields').length
          // apppend to div3  
          if (count > 20) {
            $('#div3').append(question);
          } else {
            if (count > 10) {
              $('#div2').append(question);
            }
          }
        });
```

You can also use `coccoon:before-insert` and cancel the insert if they try to enter more than 30 questions.

There are some edge cases you'll need to handle... for example if you delete a question using `link_to_remove_association` the count will be higher than the visible questions (the deleted question is just hidden) so you may need to subtract the question fields where the `_destroy` input has a value.